# Excel/Sheets Match across 2 sheets then Count

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have 2 sheets of data, and a third sheet the calculations are being performed on.
Sheet 1 has usage data with unique IDs.
Sheet 2 has the unique IDs, along with non-unique group IDs (each unique ID is only part of 1 group).
I'm trying to count the occurrence of each group ID from the given usage data by matching the unique ID to group ID.

I've been successful when creating a helper column to look up the corresponding group ID for the given unique ID within the usage sheet and counting that.  I'm trying to perform the whole set in a single calculation, I've tried COUNTIF/S with INDEX/MATCH and VLOOKUP but I can't seem to get it to return the desired value.

Example Data:
Sheet 1
Column A (uniqueid)
6904240
7196869
6917534
7008111
7242448

Sheet 2
Column A    Column I
6904240  403
7196869  103
6917534  102
7008111  102
7242448  103

Sheet 3
403 count=1
103 count=2
102 count=2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. I'm not really clear on what the difference is between Sheet1 and Sheet2. If the ID on the usage sheet is unique, why is the group on a different sheet? And if the number of rows are the same on both sheets, why do you need to count the rows on the usage sheet? Why not just count them on the sheet with the groups on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($I$2:$I$6=M2)/COUNTIFS($I$2:$I$6,$I$2:$I$6,$A$2:$A$6,$K$2:$K$6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On sheet 3, build your list of unique Group ID's in whatever way works (for instance, by using the `UNIQUE()` function on column I of sheet 2, if you have to create it dynamically). The trick to counting by Group the data organized by "Unique ID" on sheet 1 is to just be simple about it, not slick.

No helper columns are needed though that saddens me as I am a fan of them when useful.

Test each Unique ID against sheet 2's data using `XLOOKUP()` to search column I (the Group ID's) and return the matching Unique ID that the range from sheet 1 has. This test produces a collection of TRUE and FALSE which you multiply by 1 to convert to 1's and 0's, which can be summed for the count:

```
=SUM(  ($A$1:$A$14 = XLOOKUP( A1, $I$1:$I$5, $A$1:$A$5, ,0) ) *1 )
```

So, say sheet 1's Unique ID's are in A1:A14, the individual Group ID's in your unique list of them on sheet 3 is in cells A1, A2, etc. on sheet 3, and the other two ranges are sheet 2's columns A and I.

Notice the test has to be INSIDE its own set of parentheses BEFORE then doing the multiplication by 1 at the end. The lookup cell (A1 in the formula above) uses relative referencing having it look to its immediate left so you can just copy the formula straight down the column.